# What am I missing in IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Ok here is my dilemma, I have been developing on a shared host at discountasp.net (IIS 6)for some time now. All was going well, however now that app is complete we are moving it to its own dedicated server which is now server 2008 and IIS 7.

I am currently using asp forms authentication (which again seems to work just fine on IIS6)

The issue seems to occur after I click login, it pops the "Signing In" box..an error then arises in the JavaScript of Membership.js "Object Does not Support Membership.js" I verified that the code was making it to: membership.BeginLogin(uid, pwd, rememberme); and was in fact passing the correct variables.

Another odd thing I noticed when setting the forms permissions is that when I went to select Users or Roles within the IIS 7 management console it would take forever, and then time out with the following error:
A Network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not or was not accessible, verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections (provider - named pipes provider: error 40 - could not open a connection to SQL Server.)

I am rather weak on the hardware/configure side of the house so I am not really sure what the issue is, it’s almost as if IIS7 cannot see the DB.  They both reside on the same server however.  If anyone could help point me in the right direction as to how to resolve this I would be eternally grateful!

Thanks in advance
Bryan

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a web server expert either. However, I have faced the same problems when moving from IIS6 to 7.

I have put the following configuration in my Web.config to get rid of the problem:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Seems that it is required prior to run ASP.NET Ajax on IIS7.